# Read and process multiple files in R

Tags: r

I have more than 2000 txt files (each having 5 columns), each being more than 30 mb big. I would like to process through all files by read each file in and then process each of them separately and get an output and then process the next. SO I can't read them in at once and process them, since these files are too big.
But something in my code is not working correctly.

```
        files = list.files(path = "Path/to/my/Directory/", 
                   pattern = "*.txt", 
                   full.names = TRUE)


FUN = function(files) {

CSA_input_data<-fread(files)

#1
CSA_input_data[,'x21_CT'] = ((CSA_input_data[,'CASE_ALLELE_CT']/2) - CSA_input_data[,'A1_CASE_CT'])
#2
CSA_input_data[,'x21'] = CSA_input_data[,'x21_CT']/CSA_input_data[,'CASE_ALLELE_CT']

#x22
#1
CSA_input_data[,'x22_CT'] = ((CSA_input_data[,'CTRL_ALLELE_CT']/2) - CSA_input_data[,'A1_CTRL_CT'])
#2
CSA_input_data[,'x22'] = CSA_input_data[,'x22_CT']/CSA_input_data[,'CTRL_ALLELE_CT']



write.table(CSA_input_data, "Path/to/my/Directory/", sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)

}

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  FUN(files[i])
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing only directory name to write data. Change the function to

```
files = list.files(path = "Path/to/my/Directory/", 
                   pattern = "*.txt", 
                   full.names = TRUE)


FUN = function(files) {
  CSA_input_data <- data.table::fread(files)
  
  #1
  CSA_input_data[,'x21_CT'] = ((CSA_input_data[,'CASE_ALLELE_CT']/2) - CSA_input_data[,'A1_CASE_CT'])
  #2
  CSA_input_data[,'x21'] = CSA_input_data[,'x21_CT']/CSA_input_data[,'CASE_ALLELE_CT']
  
  #x22
  #1
  CSA_input_data[,'x22_CT'] = ((CSA_input_data[,'CTRL_ALLELE_CT']/2) - CSA_input_data[,'A1_CTRL_CT'])
  #2
  CSA_input_data[,'x22'] = CSA_input_data[,'x22_CT']/CSA_input_data[,'CTRL_ALLELE_CT']
  
 write.table(CSA_input_data, paste0("Path/to/my/Directory/result_", basename(files)), sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
  
}
```

and then use `lapply` or `for` loop.

```
lapply(files, FUN)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, at least the script seems to work with your help, but it only processes one file, and edits that one then. Is there a way of getting for each processed file a seperate outputfile?

Comment: ohkay..you have `full.names = TRUE`. I have used `basename(files)` to keep only the name of the file. So if you have file called abc.txt this should create a new file called result_abc.txt in the directory specified and same for all other files.